# panic: runtime error: index out of range when building docker image with terraform-provider-docker in github action runner

Tags: docker, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-docker

I am building docker images using Terraform's [`terraform-provider-docker`](https://github.com/kreuzwerker/terraform-provider-docker) in a giuhub hosted ubuntu runner.

This is the terraform configuration that builds the docker images:

```
resource "docker_registry_image" "images" {
  count = length(local.docker_images)

  name          = "${aws_ecr_repository.registries[count.index].repository_url}:${local.docker_registries[count.index].version}"
  keep_remotely = false

  build {
    context    = "${local.docker_images[count.index].context}:${replace(local.docker_image_build_trigger, "-", "")}"
    build_args = local.docker_images[count.index].build_args
  }

  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.registries, aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets]
}
```

It was working until suddenly didn't. The previous change was unrelated to docker and now the provider is not responsing and throws this error:

```
Stack trace from the terraform-provider-docker_v***.***.0 plugin:

panic: runtime error: index out of range [5***] with length 5***

goroutine ***3 [running]:
github.com***terraform-providers***terraform-provider-docker***internal***provider.buildDockerRegistryImage({0xfbeca0, 0xc00007f***0}, 0xc000036780?, 0x***d?, {0xc000036780, 0x***d})
    github.com***terraform-providers***terraform-provider-docker***internal***provider***resource_docker_registry_image_funcs.go:***56 +0x***3
github.com***terraform-providers***terraform-provider-docker***internal***provider.resourceDockerRegistryImageCreate({0xfbeca0, 0xc00007f***0}, 0x0?, {0xce5***0?, 0xc0003c***f60})
    github.com***terraform-providers***terraform-provider-docker***internal***provider***resource_docker_registry_image_funcs.go:*** +0x***be
github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-sdk***v***helper***schema.(*Resource).create(0xc000***3***8c0, {0xfbecd8, 0xc000***7a***70}, 0xd?, {0xce5***0, 0xc0003c***f60})
    github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-sdk***v***@v***.***.0***helper***schema***resource.go:707 +0x***e
github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-sdk***v***helper***schema.(*Resource).Apply(0xc000***3***8c0, {0xfbecd8, 0xc000***7a***70}, 0xc0003***c***70, 0xc000***7d***00, {0xce5***0, 0xc0003c***f60})
    github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-sdk***v***@v***.***.0***helper***schema***resource.go:837 +0xa7a
github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-sdk***v***helper***schema.(*GRPCProviderServer).ApplyResourceChange(0xc00000dda0, {0xfbecd8?, 0xc000***7a***50?}, 0xc000***30d***0)
    github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-sdk***v***@v***.***.0***helper***schema***grpc_provider.go:***0*** +0xe3c
github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-go***tfprotov5***tf5server.(*server).ApplyResourceChange(0xc000***8***d***0, {0xfbecd8?, 0xc00035b6***0?}, 0xc0005***05b0)
    github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-go@v0.***.0***tfprotov5***tf5server***server.go:8***8 +0x57***
github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-go***tfprotov5***internal***tfplugin5._Provider_ApplyResourceChange_Handler({0xe***e***80?, 0xc000***8***d***0}, {0xfbecd8, 0xc00035b6***0}, 0xc0005***05***0, 0x0)
    github.com***hashicorp***terraform-plugin-go@v0.***.0***tfprotov5***internal***tfplugin5***tfplugin5_grpc.pb.go:385 +0x***70
google.golang.org***grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc000000***e0, {0xfc***e90, 0xc000370***a0}, 0xc000***de360, 0xc00035b***0, 0x***55***d***0, 0x0)
    google.golang.org***grpc@v***.***8.0***server.go:***95 +0xb0b
google.golang.org***grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc000000***e0, {0xfc***e90, 0xc000370***a0}, 0xc000***de360, 0x0)
    google.golang.org***grpc@v***.***8.0***server.go:***636 +0xa***b
google.golang.org***grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func***.***()
    google.golang.org***grpc@v***.***8.0***server.go:93*** +0x98
created by google.golang.org***grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func***
    google.golang.org***grpc@v***.***8.0***server.go:930 +0x***8a

Error: The terraform-provider-docker_v***.***.0 plugin crashed!
```

I also tried to delete all the images and recreate the ECR registries but still getting this error.

Is it some sort of rate limit in the github action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the `context` value after the path to the folder: `"...:${replace(local.docker_image_build_trigger, "-", "")}"`. But I don't understand, it was working before.

I moved the trigger in the `build_args` and it seems working.